# Why blur filter does not work in this example

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give my form background which blurs everything behind it. There will be some content behind the form. I want this content to be visible but blurred. Should be some kind of glass effect. I'm using `filter: blur(10px);` effect. I've checked several tutorials and videos, but still can't make it to work. What am I doing wrong? Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xceg89m1/

```css
body {
  background: url(https://thecentraltrend.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tunnel.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}

#register {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 11000;
  display: table;
  color: white;
}

#registerBlock {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#registerForm {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: inherit;
}

#registerForm .blur {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  background: url(https://thecentraltrend.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tunnel.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  transform: translate(-20%, -20%);
  filter: blur(5px);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
</div>
<div id="register">
        <div id="registerBlock">
          <div id="registerForm">
            <h2>Please complete below form</h2>
            <p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
            <form method="post">
              Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="">
              <span class="error">*</span>
              <br><br>
              E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="">
              <span class="error">*</span>
              <br><br>
              Website: <input type="text" name="website" value="">
              <span class="error"></span>
              <br><br>
              Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
              <br><br>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
            <div class="blur"><img src="https://thecentraltrend.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tunnel.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Such a filter blurs the _content_ of an element. Your `.blur` element doesn’t have any actual content, just a background color.

Comment: which type of blur effect you want to show around the form. like to change the background color?

Comment: see updated http://jsfiddle.net/sft7xzao/34/

Answer (score 2):

Blur actually blurs content inside that object. It doesn't blur everything beneath the div. For example, if you add the image inside of the div, you will notice the blur effect works as expected.

```
<div class="blur">
    <img src="https://thecentraltrend.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tunnel.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it actually works for its purpose, but I need content behind the form to be visible but blurred. I've updated my fiddle, added some text for the example. Is there a way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve blur effect this way

```css
body {
  background: url(https://thecentraltrend.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tunnel.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}

.test{
  filter: blur(1px);
}

#register {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 11000;
  display: table;
  color: white;
  filter: blur(0px) !important;
}

#registerBlock {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#registerForm {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: inherit;
}

#registerForm .blur {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  background: url(https://thecentraltrend.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tunnel.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  transform: translate(-20%, -20%);
  opacity:0.5;
  filter: blur(5px);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="test">
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
</div>
<div id="register">
        <div id="registerBlock">
          <div id="registerForm">
            <h2>Please complete below form</h2>
            <p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
            <form method="post">
              Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="">
              <span class="error">*</span>
              <br><br>
              E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="">
              <span class="error">*</span>
              <br><br>
              Website: <input type="text" name="website" value="">
              <span class="error"></span>
              <br><br>
              Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
              <br><br>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
            <div class="blur"><img src="https://thecentraltrend.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tunnel.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it actually works for its purpose, but I need content behind the form to be visible but blurred. I've updated my fiddle, added some text for the example. Is there a way to achieve this effect?

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze Please see my updated answer, i already update your jsfiddle

Comment: I need form background to be partially transparent and the content just behind the form div to be blurred, not all the content. Is that possible?

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze see the updated jsfiiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xceg89m1/9/
you mean like that

Comment: Now the blur effect is lost... Seems like there is no direct css way to accomplish this. I just found a 'backdrop-filter' property, which is being developed right now, but it's not supported for all browsers. I'll take a look. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze see my updated answer and i also update your jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xceg89m1/15/

Comment: Close one! But the content behind is still not blurred, only the front image. Blurring the content behind is more important, because the background of the form might be as image as a simple rgba color.

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze see this with content - http://jsfiddle.net/xceg89m1/21/

Comment: Now content around the form is invisible... Guess I should just leave it without blurring. Thank you for trying :)